# Should our pet tags be plural or singular?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

So far, there are more questions tagged as plural than singular. However, there is already a duplicate:

[cat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat) and [cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats)

One should be made a synonym of the other. Additionally, we've got [rabbit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbit) which is the only other singular tag so far. I think it should be consistent across the board. So, what's the consensus?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Personally, I feel like the plural sounds more natural, and since the questions can relate to more than one of each animal, make a bit more semantic sense.

If we find that the singular/plural thing becomes an issue as people are adding and creating new tags, it is possible to create synonyms and the like, but on the whole, I feel like the plurals feel more natural.

Comment: I agree, questions are likely to be about "cats" and not "cat" as it were.

Comment: I agree, but I'm the idiot who created the dog tag with a typo. If someone else uses it, let try to edit it out so it gets killed tonight, or make it a synonym of dogs.

Comment: if we edit it out as/if it appears, it should age out and disappear, so lets try for that!

Comment: I agree that plurals are more natural.  Once the plural tag exists, anybody who starts typing the singular will be offered it, so once we clean up the initial singular tags we should be good.