# Chameleon(s) tag

Tags: support, retagging

For [a question about chameleons](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/738/how-to-heal-a-wounded-chameleon) I tried to remove the singular [chameleon](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chameleon) and instead add [chameleons](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chameleons) as per our meta discussion on [tag plurals](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-our-pet-tags-be-plural-or-singular) but I get a message saying

> You are attempting to create the tag [chameleons]; however the tag [chameleon] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.